# Copy CSV field to next row (same column) if blank - Bash (preferably)

Tags: bash, csv

Basically (said slightly tongue-in-cheek) I have a csv file in a format like this:

```
"ID","Name","Phone Number"
"00001","Ricky Stallman","07771111111"
"00003","Harrison Ford","07701010101"
"00003","Harrison Ford",""
"00008","Bob Geldof","07712121212"
```

Where the 'Harrison Ford' entry appears again in my csv there's no number next to it (it's just the way the data is annoyingly presented to me). I need the csv to read like this (i.e with the number from the row above to be copied into the field below):

```
"ID","Name","Phone Number"
"00001","Ricky Stallman","07771111111"
"00003","Harrison Ford","07701010101"
"00003","Harrison Ford","07701010101"
"00008","Bob Geldof","07712121212"
```

Preferably in Bash if anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F',' '$3!~/""/{nbr=$3} {print $1","$2","nbr}' file
```

If the third column is "" then use the last valid value.

Comment: Wow! That was quick! Absolutely perfect!! Just what I needed, just saved me literally days of work there

Comment: I guess that should be enough if lines of same person are adjacent to each other or else it would copy the previous line's number which is of another person. Since it appears that entries are sorted I guess there won't be a problem to that.

Comment: Is is enough: "the number from the row above to be copied into the field below" (as long as the row above has a valid value).

Comment: If we base literally from what the OP said that is.

Comment: Yes, they're always adjacent (fortunately!). @konsolbox yours works fine too :)

Comment: There would also be a problem if X person only has a single entry and that single entry's number is empty so be careful with that as well. It could also apply if it has multiple entries but the first one is actually the one has been empty, even if they are adjacent.

Answer (score 2):

A gawk solution could be used:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

match($0, /"([^\"]*)".*,"([^"]*)","([^"]*)"/, t) {
    key = t[1] "|" t[2]  ## Or just key = t[2] to be less strict.
    if (!(t[3] == "" && key in a)) {
        a[key] = t[3]
    }
    printf "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"\"%s\"\n", t[1], t[2], a[key]
}
```

Condensed:

```
gawk 'match($0, /"([^\"]*)".*,"([^"]*)","([^"]*)"/, t) { key = t[1] "|" t[2]; if (!(t[3] == "" && key in a)) a[key] = t[3]; printf "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", t[1], t[2], a[key] }' file
```

Output:

```
"ID","Name","Phone Number"
"00001","Ricky Stallman","07771111111"
"00003","Harrison Ford","07701010101"
"00003","Harrison Ford","07701010101"
"00008","Bob Geldof","07712121212"
```